# How to transfer a particular API KEY to another account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Situation is very critical and need experts help.

We released our APK in the market already. But the API KEY was created using developer’s own google account. Unfortunately he left our company.

We contacted him and requested him to transfer it to our account. He agreed, but he has his own API KEY in the same project. So finally he turned his face in another direction. He asked us to find the way to transfer only that API KEY that we need.

I searched in internet but, hell, I could not find.
So we are in trouble as our app is being used by the users.

Any soulution?

Thanks in advanched

Comment: what happens if you create a new key and publish a new apk with new api key?

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer an API key, you should either be part of the user's project, or generate a new API Key within your project. However, for installed application, it's recommended to use [OAuth 2.0 authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)